# Replace newlines in Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Cannot find and replace newlines in a Google doc.

This works (just showing that I have a body, and can replace):

```
bulletinBody.getBody().editAsText().replaceText("x","y");
```

These do not work:

```
bulletinBody.getBody().editAsText().replaceText("\\n","y");
bulletinBody.getBody().editAsText().replaceText("\\r","y");
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can.  The doc is divided into paragraph elements.  When you type Enter it creates a new paragraph, not a new line character.  As of 2019 https://support.google.com/docs/thread/9648924/how-to-use-find-replace-to-replace-newline-n-with-soft-linebreak-or-vertical-tab-v?hl=en

Comment: Hmm. The end goal is to eliminate sequences of blank lines. In other words, turn multiple blank lines into single blank lines. Basically, it seems like I need to find "empty" paragraphs and delete them. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me~

```js
  let doc = DocumentApp.openById('***')
  let body = doc.getBody()
  let children = body.getNumChildren()
  while (children) {
    children -= 1
    let item = body.getChild(children)
    if (item.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      if (!item.asText().getText()) {
        item.merge()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I ended up approaching the problem a different way. But this looks great, I may need it. Thank you!